# Hub Site Redirect

Tags: sharepoint-online

In sharepoint hub sites/ Is it possible to redirect to a subsite based on users target audiance. Our organization has several different locations, and the requirement his once the users is visit/log in into the main site, he would be redirected a location site first. The users could eventually go to that subsite later on, but would have to navigate to it. Is there a document of some sort that would allow this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OOB solution for targeted users redirection. You will need customization to achieve this requirement.

See a similar post here for reference:
[Check user from sharepoint group and redirect.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85296/check-user-from-sharepoint-group-and-redirect)